# File handling in tinyos or tossim

Tags: sensors, tinyos, nesc

I need to read data from a text file in a tinyos file (nesc file). I searched lot on Internet but couldn't find a way.

Is there any way?

Comment: Read txt file from where? from the flash memory or sd card?!

Comment: from hard disk, when doing tossim simulation

Comment: AFAIK, There is no way to directly read from a PC on a sensor board....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about TOSSIM, but using a real sensor board its possible to do so.

What you could do, is to write a program using Java, C#, etc that reads the file and passes the acquired data to the serial/usb port as a SERIAL PACKET. But you are limited to maximum of 255 byte for each packet.

So you should make a simple protocol that takes care of data chunks.

Of course you should know that how you can create a serial packet to be readable by sensor boards.

For that you need to read the [TEP#113](http://tinyos.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tinyos/tinyos-2.x/doc/html/tep113.html). But short story, a serial packet is consisted of:

HEADER + CONTENT + FOOTER

header contains protocol byte, destination and source address etc...
content is your message_t struct
footer has CRC and some other stuff

You have to take care of CRC calculation and also escaping start/end delimeters (I believe byte 126 or 127 is the delimiter, I mean indicator of starting and ending a packet).